# How to Show Data After Login in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, show

After successfully login from auth, I wan to show the data from database. But I got an error like this.

> Undefined variable: barangs (View: C:\xampp7\htdocs\example-app\resources\views\barang.blade.php)
> in c1126675c0e1af0f5c253b69d8a8d64d968d987a.php line 188

and this is the login controller

```
    class loginController extends Controller
{
   function auth(Request $req){

        $username = $req->input('your_name');
        $password = md5($req->input('your_pass'));

        $chekLogin = DB::table('user')->where(['username'=>$username,'password'=>$password])->get();
        if(count($chekLogin) > 0 ){
           
         return view('barang');
        }
        else {
           echo " Login Failed, Wrong Data";
        }
      ;

   }

}
```

and this is my barangController

```
    class barangController extends Controller
{
   public function data(){

        $barangs = DB::table('barang')->get();
        //return $barangs;
        return view('barang',['barangs'=>$barangs]);
   }
}
```

this is my barang.blade.php

```
<div class="x_content">
                  <p class="text-muted font-13 m-b-30">
                   Info Barang
                  </p>
                  <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>Kode Barang</th>
                        <th>Nama Barang</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @foreach ($barangs as $item)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$item->kode_barang}}</td>
                        <td>{{$item->nama_barang}}</td>
                        <td><a href="" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

and this is my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
Route::post('auth','loginController@auth')->name('login.auth');

Route::get('databarang', 'barangController@data');
```

please help me,I dont know why barang is not defined in here, may I forgot to add something? Thankyou before

Comment: You getting this error from your login controller, where you defined `return view('barang');` Here you did not pass the `barangs` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you're not including the `barangs` data when you return your `view` in the `auth` function.

Instead of returning a `view` from your `auth`, redirect the `user`:

```
if(count($chekLogin) > 0 ){
    return redirect(url('databarang'));
}
```

What this will do is redirect your `user` to the route which then returns your `view('barang')` but includes the missing `barangs` data.

Comment: thank you for your answer, now it working :))